# Converting a DateTime? to DateTime in a setter function in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api

I have a contract of a response from a WEBApi which returns Nullable DateTime. But I need it to be only DateTime, making the value DateTime.MaxValue in case it is null.

```
private DateTime endDate;
public DateTime? EndDate
    {
        get { return endDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
            else
            {
                endDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this approach will require me to explicitly convert DateTime? to DateTime all throughout my code. So, I was wondering how the Setter function would work? Will it be initialized first and then the DataType checked? If so, then I can replace the above code with the one below:

```
private DateTime endDate;
public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get { return endDate; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
            else
            {
                endDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this possible? Or does the Setter function get called after the DataType check during the deserialization?

Comment: what should the default look like? `DateTime.MaxValue` also?

Comment: Yes, default is DateTime.MaxValue

Comment: I think your only option is to use the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: he wants to avoid using the `null-coalescing operator` everywhere he accesses this property throughout his code. The point is that it cannot be null because `DateTime.MaxValue` is the new value in case it was null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not possible, the passed value must have the same type as the property. You could use another property in your code :

```
public DateTime? ApiEndDate { get; set; }

public DateTime EndDate => ApiEndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue;
```

Now the api uses the property `ApiEndData`(if you can't rename it leave it as `EndDate` and rename the other) and you can use the other property in your code.

Answer (score 3):

No, that isn't possible. You can make a defaulting property to get the value:

```
public DateTime EndDateOrDefault
{
    get { return endDate; }
}
```

And call that property in your code. You can keep your current property to comply to your service contract.

Comment: So, then the data type would be checked prior to the setter function being called?

Comment: Your current property remains as-is, so that won't change the requirements for your service. Just call this property in all your code to prevent having to call `.Value` every time.